# what is the best way to add ng-class with one complex condition

Tags: angularjs

How can I integrate both ng-classes

```
ng-class="{removeBtn:'selected'}[resource.check_added_to_plan]" && ng-class="'lastSpan':($index+1)%3==0}"
```

If resource.check_added_to_plan is "removeBtn" then I need to add "selected" class

Thanks

Comment: ng-class="{removeBtn:'selected', 'lastSpan':($index+1)%3==0}[resource.check_added_to_plan]" I have tried this but the "selected" class is being added but the lastSpan class is not showing it's property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure, what are you trying to achieve, but you need to fix syntax errors and do something like this:

```
ng-class="{removeBtn: resource.check_added_to_plan, lastSpan: ($index+1)%3==0}"
```

So, in a form `class1: condition1, class2: condition2, etc...`

Comment: Hi Shomz ,I have edited the ques as per my requirement...Thanks

Comment: Hi, does `resource.check_added_to_plan` contain an actual class name?

Comment: Oh ya...,It's working with yours given expression ,I have modified as ng-class="{'selected': resource.check_added_to_plan=='removeBtn','lastSpan':($index+1)%3==0}"    ...................Thanks

Comment: Ah, now I see what you wanted! :) Anyways, I'm glad I could help.